# tikz-timing: How to change size of names of all signals

Tags: tikz-timing

I want the **names of the signals** to be **smaller**.

*Questions*:

1. How do I make only one smaller?
2. How do I preconfigure that all signals of all graphics generated in the document to have a smaller size for the signal names?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\begin{document}
This is a test graphic.\\

    \begin{tikztimingtable}
            clk & 21{C}; \\
            data  &  5L;2H;14L \\
    \end{tikztimingtable}

Another graphic, but i want the size of all signal names to be smaller.\\

    \begin{tikztimingtable}
            clksmallersize  & 21{C}; \\
            data2  &  5L;2H;14L \\
    \end{tikztimingtable}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

% The following lines makes all signal names smaller in all document
%\tikzset{timing/name/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize}} 

\begin{document}
This is a test graphic.\\

    \begin{tikztimingtable}
            clk & 21{C}; \\
            data  &  5L;2H;14L \\
    \end{tikztimingtable}

Another graphic, with names of signals smaller.\\

% adding this in brackets, makes the signals of the tikztimingtable smaller, only for that table.
    \begin{tikztimingtable}[timing/name/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize}]
            clk\_smallersize    & 21{C}; \\
            data\_smallersize &  5L;2H;14L \\
    \end{tikztimingtable}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]